# How to use cfg-dump option with Clang 3.0?

Tags: llvm, clang

I had tried to do following post:
http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/CFG-dump-in-clang-td2076047.html

Like this:
`clang -cc1 -analyze -cfg-dump test.cpp`

However, I got this warning:
`error: unknown argument: '-cfg-dump'`

How can I use cfg-dump option?
Do not Clang 3.0 have cfg-dump option?

Comment: Welcome to llvm! You should thank god if tool built for one llvm version works on another llvm version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was [renamed at Feb 17 15:39:39 CST 2011](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20110214/038974.html), Revision: 125780

> '-cfg-dump' is replaced by '-analyzer-checker=debug.DumpCFG'
>
> '-dump-live-variables' is replaced by '-analyzer-checker=debug.DumpLiveVars'
>
> '-cfg-view' is replaced by '-analyzer-checker=debug.ViewCFG'

Update: according to haruna in comments, '`-analyzer`'  option is needed to use any analyzer-checker.

Comment: I had can get CFG like this :`clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=debug.DumpCFG test.cpp`Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the comment, this went unnoticed by me and I can finally get this to work too :)